# How to restore a HP backup with unreadable SWM files

Tags: windows, data-recovery

I backed up my laptop to an external HDD using HP backup & restore tool. It has compressed the files and saved them into several files with an SWM extension.

Now it seems as if the external HDD I've used may be faulty, because some of those SWM files can't be read, and the restore is is failing with error message FFFFFF15.

Is there any way I can recover data from the SWM files that can be read. If not, what are my other options?

Comment: All I can suggest is see if 7-Zip can extract the data from those compressed files. Also see this page...https://file.org/extension/swm